# offset-4 elements do not line up

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This is a very basic question (learning Bootstrap/Bootstrap4).

I don't understand why the "button" below is not left aligned with the two elements above it. I've tried lots of variations but I still don't get it.

I'm not "looking for the codez" as much as looking for the flaw in my understanding here. There is no other CSS active.

---

[image]

---

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="project-directory" class="col-4 col-form-label text-right">Project Directory</label>
                        <input type="text" class="col col-6 form-control" id="project-directory" placeholder="Select directory. . .">
                        <small class="offset-4 form-text text-muted mb-3">Select or create the directory where the project should be saved</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col offset-4">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Update:** Ok – using the Chrome dev tools, I can now see the added padding for `col`(Should have thought to look before asking the question). I was following a video tutorial and I thought the instructor stated that `col` was to be added to each element, even if tags like `col-4` or `offset-2` were also added. Seemed redundant to me – but there seems a lot that is redundant – like the use of `btn btn-primary`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="offset-4">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
</div>
```

You have used **col class**. by default bootstrap set padding-left: 15px; for the **col** class. 
class="col" is the reason for the space/alignment.

https://codepen.io/rajibchandrakarmaker/pen/mjmYpM

Comment: So is `col col-4` redundant? I was going through a Lynda.com video tutorial where that was presented as the way to do it. Or maybe I misunderstood. Seems redundant – just like `btn btn-primary` – but I have seen that all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

It's because different elements respond in different ways to having the col-4 class. Adjusting it to only use divs, everything aligns:

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-4">First</div>
                  <div class="col-6">Second</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col offset-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```